# Direction API google - direction request failed due to not found

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to show the distance between two points. but i am facing this error **direction request failed due to not found**. I googled but not found a solution. Please have a look at my code and tell me if i am doing something wrong.

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    var markerArray = [];

    // Instantiate a directions service.
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

    // Create a map and center it on Manhattan.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {lat: 40.771, lng: -73.974}
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    var stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Display the route between the initial start and end selections.
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(
        directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);

    // Listen to change events from the start and end lists.
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(
          directionsDisplay, directionsService, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsDisplay, directionsService,
      markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
    // First, remove any existing markers from the map.
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
      markerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }

    // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using
    // WALKING directions.
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    }, function(response, status) {
      // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
      // markers for each step.
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        document.getElementById('warnings-panel').innerHTML =
            '<b>' + response.routes[0].warnings + '</b>';
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        showSteps(response, markerArray, stepDisplay, map);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function showSteps(directionResult, markerArray, stepDisplay, map) {
    // For each step, place a marker, and add the text to the marker's infowindow.
    // Also attach the marker to an array so we can keep track of it and remove it
    // when calculating new routes.
    var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
      var marker = markerArray[i] = markerArray[i] || new google.maps.Marker;
      marker.setMap(map);
      marker.setPosition(myRoute.steps[i].start_location);
      attachInstructionText(
          stepDisplay, marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions, map);
    }
  }

  function attachInstructionText(stepDisplay, marker, text, map) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on, containing the text
      // of the step.
      stepDisplay.setContent(text);
      stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
```

Html side :

```
    <input id="start" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="picup lock">

    <input id="end" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="drop off">
```

Comment: What are the start and end values that you are using when you get `ZERO_RESULTS`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Are you really using the deprecated and turned off [google-maps-api-2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info)?

Comment: no, its not turned off and its working fine

Comment: It looks to me like you are actually using the [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-3/info), if so, you should fix the tag on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsStatus), error **NOT_FOUND** indicates at least one of the locations specified in the request's origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.

Make sure that point1 and point3 are not empty. The API doesn't know how to create a route from "" to "".

Check this related [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663625/javascript-jquery-google-maps-routes-not-found) and [tutorial](http://www.dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/using_geolocation_to_automatically_generate_a_route_and_directions_in_google_maps.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday, using the API via C# httpClient. But the same request worked fine in a browser. After a bit of debugging I found out that it only worked if I sent Accept-Language header in the httpClient…